# restrict login attempts in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication

I've done some looking into this topic but haven't found much that seemed to answer the question. I'm looking to implement code that restricts the number of failed login attempts for an iOS application. Is this something that can be functionally handled by the SDK, i.e. in the URL Loading System? Thanks for any input. It is appreciated.

Comment: What authentication method are you using?

Comment: What is attempting to log into what? If you are trying to limit an iOS app logging into a server that is the server's job to restrict logins. From a security perspective consider that an attacker will not use your app but instead write their own app to circumvent any client-side restrictions.

Comment: @Zaph But couldn't an attacker only use their own app if they owned the client device? I'm trying to implement something at the client device that counts the number of failed attempts and after some number of failures prevent further attempts. Or should the client not actually handle that functionality?

Comment: Define what you are trying to protect. As one case, if access to the server must be restricted the server must provide the protection, a client can not be counted on to provide that protection. Eve will write her own client implementation to obtain access to the server. If the thing to be protected is on the client that is the client's job.